# Serialize and Deserialize Oracle.DataAccess.OracleException in C#

Tags: c#, exception, serialization, deserialization, oracleexception

OracleException has no public constructors nor any way to get a new instance. I tried my XmlSerializerHelper class, but it requires a public parameterless constructor.

I used BinaryFormatter to serialize the OracleException and wrote it to a file.

How can I serialize OracleException  in a file, and deserialize too using XmlSerializer -for testing reasons-?.

Reference:
http://geekswithblogs.net/WillSmith/archive/2008/07/25/testing-oracleexception.aspx

PD: Is better SoapFormatter or BinaryFormatter ?

Code

```
SerializationHelper.Serialize(@"C:\Temp\ExcepcionOracle.bin", ex);

var exOra = SerializationHelper.Deserialize(@"C:\Temp\ExcepcionOracle.bin");


public static void Serialize(string fileName, Object obj)
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
            try
            {
                binaryFormatter.Serialize(fileStream, obj);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("The object graph could not be serialized", ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
        }


        public static object Deserialize(string fileName)
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            var fileStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            try
            {
                fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(fileStream);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Serialization Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Why do you need to serialize and deserialize an exception?

Comment: Re `BinaryFormatter` vs `SoapFormatter`... well, I would argue strongly "neither", but `SoapFormatter` is *officially* to be avoided (MSDN notes it is obsolete). `BinaryFormatter` is still hanging on by fingernails... The only time **I** use `BinaryFormatter` is to poke fun at it.

Answer (score 0):

things like `Exception` simply aren't very suitable for xml serializers (and `XmlSerializer` in particular). In addition to the constructor issues (which some serializers can work around, and some can't), you are also likely to get issues with unexpected subclasses and arbitrary data in the collection.

If you are serializing as xml, you should probably just capture the key information you need - maybe the `.Message` and a few other things. Note also that in a client/server application the client doesn't really need to know much of the particulars of the failure - that should remain at the server. Either it is an *exected* error (invalid parameters, login issues, quota restrictions, etc), or it is an *unexpected* error. In the latter case: **just say an unexpected error happened**. The details would only be useful to a developer, and a developer should already have access to the server's error log.

Comment: Agreed. Still, aren't all exceptions supposed to be marked [Serializable] and provide default constructors (for completely different reasons, e.g. remoting)? FxCop keeps nagging me about that... Are Oracle not following "best practices" here?

Comment: @Anders that is only useful to `BinaryFormatter`; the OP is asking about `XmlSerializer`

Comment: I know. I was just pointing out that this whole problem is because Oracle apparently hasn't followed the design guidelines which say that exceptions should have a public no-arg constructor. That said, I do agree that exceptions should not be passed to a client in this scenario.

Comment: @Anders it depends - for all I know, maybe this is an abstract base-class for a few different private exception types... horses for courses